# Global substitution for latex commands in vim

Tags: regex, vim, latex

I am writing a long document and I am frequently formatting some terms to italics. After some time I realized that maybe that is now what I want so I would like to remove all the latex commands that format text to italics.

Example:

`\textit{Vim} is undoubtedly one of the best editors ever made. \textit{LaTeX} is an extremely powerful, intelligent typesetter. \textbd{Vim-LaTeX} aims at bringing together the best of both these worlds`

How can I run a substitution command that recognizes all the instances of `\textit{whatever}` and changes them to just `whatever` without affecting different commands such as `\textbd{Vim-LaTeX}` in this example?

EDIT: As technically the answer that helps is the one from Igor I will mark that one as the correct one. Nevertheless, Konrad's answer should be taken into account as it shows the proper Latex strategy to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this substitution command:

```
% s/\\textit{\([^}]*\)}/\1/
```

If textit can span muptiple lines:

```
%! perl -e 'local $/; $_=<>; s/\\textit{([^}]*)}/$1/g; print;'
```

And you can do this without perl also:

```
%s/\\textit{\(\_.\{-}\)}/\1/g
```

Here:

- `\_.` -- any symbol including a newline character
- `\{-}` -- make `*` non-greedy.

Comment: That works as I need, but as @gerrit said I doesn't work for multiple lines. Using the `s` flag didn't fix it.

Comment: @gerrit: thank you for the suggestion; I've added another (multiline capable) solution

Comment: Ok. I don't seem to be able to undo my downvote, see 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71121/cant-undo-my-vote-even-after-the-answer-i-voted-on-was-editing

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn’t use formatting commands at all in your text.

LaTeX is built around the idea of *semantic markup*. So instead of saying “this text should be italic” you should mark up the text using its *function*. For instance:

```tex
\product{Vim} is undoubtedly one of the best editors ever made. \product{LaTeX}
is an extremely powerful, intelligent typesetter. \product{Vim-LaTeX} aims at
bringing together the best of both these worlds
```

… and then, in your preamble, a package, or a document class, you (re-)define a macro `\product` to set the formatting you want. That way, you can adapt the macro whenever you deem necessary without having to change the code.

Or, if you want to remove the formatting completely, just make the macro display its bare argument:

```tex
\newcommand*\product[1]{#1}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand your point, nevertheless I would still be in the same problem: `\product{whatever}` to just `whatever`

Comment: You can redefine `\product{whatever}` to be a command that does nothing at all. Then, in the final PDF, it would be just the same as if you had written `whatever`. If you need help, come over to tex.SE.